# Update key names and values in a key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a key-value pair like this:

```
apple foo1
banana foo2
oranges foo3
notapple foo4
notapple foo5
notbanana foo6
maybeoranges foo7
```

I want to change the last 4 pairs to `apple, banana, oranges` respectively and add a fixed prefix to their values say `test-`. What's the best way to do this?

Right now I'm doing this:

```py
if key == "notapple":
   key = "apple"
   value = "test-" + value
if key == "notbanana":
   key = "banana"
   value = "test-" + value
if key == "maybeoranges":
   key = "oranges"
   value = "test-" + value
```

Too many if condition's are becoming unwieldy. Is there a better way to do this?

Maybe the `if`-s can be combined somehow?

Answer (score 2):

As there are multiple keys with same name, it can't be declared as dict. Instead we can declare only as 2-dimensional list.

```
kvpair = [['apple', 'foo1'],
         ['banana', 'foo2'],
         ['oranges', 'foo3'],
         ['notapple', 'foo4'],
         ['notapple', 'foo5'],
         ['notbanana', 'foo6'],
         ['maybeoranges', 'foo7']]

fruitlst = ['apple', 'banana', 'oranges']
for i, x in enumerate(kvpair):
    for y in fruitlst:
        if y in x[0] and x[0].find(y) != 0:
            kvpair[i][0] = y
            kvpair[i][1] = f'test-{x[1]}'
            break
print(kvpair)

#Output: [['apple', 'foo1'], ['banana', 'foo2'], ['oranges', 'foo3'], ['apple', 'test-foo4'], ['apple', 'test-foo5'], ['banana', 'test-foo6'], ['oranges', 'test-foo7']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a list of key/value pairs as tuples then:

```
KVP = [
    ("apple", "foo1"),
    ("banana", "foo2"),
    ("oranges", "foo3"),
    ("notapple", "foo4"),
    ("notapple", "foo5"),
    ("notbanana", "foo6"),
    ("maybeoranges", "foo7"),
]

FRUITS = {"apple", "banana", "oranges"}

def fixup(t: tuple[str, str]) -> tuple[str, str]:
    k, v = t
    if not k in FRUITS:
        for fruit in FRUITS:
            if k.endswith(fruit):
                return "test-" + fruit, v
    return t

KVP = list(map(fixup, KVP))

print(KVP)
```

**Output:**

```
[('apple', 'foo1'), ('banana', 'foo2'), ('oranges', 'foo3'), ('test-apple', 'foo4'), ('test-apple', 'foo5'), ('test-banana', 'foo6'), ('test-oranges', 'foo7')]
```